# prevent / ban a member from renewing

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to flag a contact who has been banned from renewing their membership?

This is on a wordpress site that uses the Members Sync to automatically assign users to roles.  I thought about creating using a "banned" role but they would also be in an Alumni group automatically which I suspect would trump this if trying to use the ACL.

Comment: wild thought would be to use something like civi rules, put your banned person in a group, and then via civirules see if you can set up so that 'if person is in group x' and 'if person gets membership' then 'set membership to cancelled'. totally untested idea.

Answer (score 1):

Set their existing membership type with a status of cancelled and use a permanent override.

Comment: Unfortunately their membership dashboard still shows a [Renew Now] link.  licking on this allows them to pay for a new membership.  Good idea but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, thought what Andy suggested should work, but if it doesn't on your end, you could try this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-extra-restrict-signup-and-renewal-membership-include-exclude-search

Full disclosure: I've never used this extension, but have been eyeing it as we think we might have a good use for it. In your case, you could use the group option for restricting.